# Setting the height of a view in dp units by code?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I was wondering if it's possibly to change the height of a LinearLayout in my java code from something like 100dp to 200dp ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, this.getResources()
        .getDisplayMetrics()));
```

also you can add a dimension in values and get it from resources.

[Dimension values](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations

It can help you convert dp to px. This px value you can set in LayoutParams. Hope it's useful

Answer (score 0):

```
// The gesture threshold expressed in dp
private static final float GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP = 16.0f;

// Get the screen's density scale
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
// Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
mGestureThreshold = (int) (GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP * scale + 0.5f);

// Use mGestureThreshold as a distance in pixels...
```

The `DisplayMetrics.density` field specifies the scale factor you must use to convert `dp` units to pixels, according to the current screen density. On a medium-density screen, `DisplayMetrics.density` equals `1.0;` on a high-density screen it equals `1.5;` on an extra high-density screen, it equals `2.0;` and on a low-density screen, it equals `0.75`. This figure is the factor by which you should multiply the `dp` units on order to get the actual pixel count for the current screen. (Then add `0.5f` to round the figure up to the nearest whole number, when converting to an integer.) For more information, refer to the [DisplayMetrics class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html).

*Answer from [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations) so you don't have to search for content*